# How to launch Chrome's Secure Shell ssh plugin via web link

Tags: ssh, putty, google-chrome

I am looking to figure out how to create a URL or link that executes a client side SSH session.  I found the Chrome extension called 'Secure Shell', but the documentation is rather minimal.

Basically, the behavior I'm looking for is:

```
1) user is presented with a list of VM links
2) user clicks a link
3) user's client system starts an SSH session
4) if this is the first time the session has been started, the user is 
   prompted to select the appropriate authentication method (i.e. enter 
   username/password or select ssh key, etc.)
5) if this is not the first time the session has been started, the 
   client remembers the user's previous selections and opens the client 
   using those selections
```

Is there a way to do this either with Secure Shell or some other plugin/application?

Answer (score 0):

The same concepts apply as regular web page links. Just call the protocol directly and it will only work in chrome. below is a sample how to do this.

```
<HTML>
<body>
<a href="chrome-extension://pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo/html/nassh.html">Secure Shell</a>
</body>
</HTML>
```